# safe form layout user preferences

Tags: java, eclipse

When my software runs some forms appear and user can expand or close or minimize them. I want to save user changes(all close,minimize and expand)for user .How is it possible to save user preferences?

Answer (score 1):

In windows, you can save these settings into registry for user.

```
Preferences.userRoot().put("User_settings", "some settings");
```

The first argument is key, the second value. But this works under Windows only!

Nice solution is also saving of these settings into config file for each user (don't know if this si possible for you, don't know architecture of your program).

Comment: I don't know how can I define registry for each user?My program is like a game that when a user save its game I want to save his preferences.

Comment: This will define it. It will save to windows user registry...thats why userRoot() method is called.

Comment: This isn't really Windows-specific. The Preferences framework also works on other systems (not putting it into the registry, of course).